# How can you map the exceedance of a threshold into an activation function of a Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am totally new to Artificial Neural Networks. Let’s say that the model you are trying to turn into an artificial neural network has an output that is triggered *only* by the exceedance of a threshold: $y\geq y_{1}. $Therefore, you need to find a way to use this inequality as an activation function. Is this feasible?

Comment: Do you know $y_1$ or is that something to be learned?

Comment: @JanvanderVegt I already know `y1`. Shall I use a Unit Step function as an activation function? I am learning something in the process.

Comment: A problem with doing that is that derivates are not able to flow through that anymore. But I don't think I fully understand the issue, if you know $y_1$ already, can't you transform your input? Can you give an example usecase?

Comment: Yes, I can do that. But then I don't need an activation function anymore, because the inequality would result in a binary case: it's either `0` or `1`. In that case, would that still be a neural network?

Comment: Can you give an example use case? If you have a binary switch then you cannot train the network properly because of not having proper subgradients flowing with backpropagation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is feasable. This is also called a `Binary/Step` activation function. You must only use this activation function on the output neurons.

The `Step` function will round down an answer that is lower than 0.5 to `0`, and an answer that is higher than 0.5 to `1`. However, please note that you do not need to use a binary activation function to output 1 - I advise you to just use TanH or sigmoid and backpropagate a whole bunch of iterations.

However, in other comments, you mentioned that you know what `y1` is. *That is not of importance*, the network will act as a black box and will figure out a treshold itself. Don't set up your own activation function just to get the right output - that avoids the whole point of backpropagation.